# Blank page in pdf with Flying Saucer

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, flying-saucer

I'm facing an issue pretty annoying, each time i'm trying to play with page selector, a blank page is created.
Just to avoid some duplicate flag, I have tried all the solutions given in related questions, but none works

css

```
    @page {
        size: a4 portrait;
    }  

    @page land { 
        size: a4 landscape;
    }

    .landscapePage { 
        page:land; height: 21cm; width: 28.6cm
    }
```

html

```
    <div>
        Portrait 1
    </div>
    <div class="landscapePage">
        landscape 1
    </div>
    <div>
        Portrait 2
    </div>
```

The following html give a four pages pdf with :

- portrait 1
- landscape 1
- blank page *(which is obviously unwanted)*
- portrait 2

Any suggestion on how to remove this blank page?

Comment: do a print preview in your browser, it is probably a matter of tighten up your  content a bit on the previous page (reduced margins and or padding).

Comment: I tested it exactly how I posted it, so it's not a size content problem, there is only written "portrait 1", etc, in each page

Comment: It looks like you might need to set a width and height on your second portrait because it comes after a landscape because of a bug https://recalll.co/app/?q=pdf%20generation%20-%20getting%20extra%20blank%20pdf%20page%20in%20Flying%20Saucer/iText

Comment: You are right, thanks for the help (post it in answer, i'll accept it)

Comment: The answer is not mine I just lucked in with the google foo so all cool.

Comment: So as a lot of answers in a lot of questions. But as you please =p